# What's the best way to strip out only the anchor HTML tags in javascript, given a string of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, text

Let's say there's a string of HTML, with script tags, plain text, whatever.

What's the best way to strip out only the `<a>` tags?

I've been using some methods here, but these are for all tags.  [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: Do you want to preserve the contents of the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var content = $('<div>' + htmlString + '</div>');
content.find('a').replaceWith(function() { return this.childNodes; });
var newHtml = content.html();
```

Adding a wrapping `<div>` tag allows us to get the desired HTML back.

I wrote a [more detailed explanation](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/modifying-html-strings-using-jquery.html) on my blog.

Comment: This may cause unexpected side-effects, such as breaking event handlers attached to any of the elements touched.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: He has a _string_.  There aren't any event handlers.  Had he not had a string, fixed.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks for pointing that out, I missed it. I did provide an alternative approach in another answer in case someone is trying to accomplish the same thing within a DOM structure.

Comment: @eyelidlessness: I think I already fixed that.  `.contents()` returns actual DOM elements, so handlers should be preserved.  (I'm too lazy to check)

Comment: @SLaks, I missed that. Cheers (+1).

Comment: If `htmlString` is controlled by an attacker then on some browsers it can cause redirects via `<meta>` tags, or via `<img src=javascript:...>`.

Answer (score 3):

This approach will preserve existing DOM nodes, minimizing side-effects if you have elements within the anchors that have events attached to them.

```
function unwrapAnchors() {
    if(!('tagName' in this) || this.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a' || !('parentNode' in this)) {
        return;
    }
    var childNodes = this.childNodes || [], children = [], child;
    // Convert childNodes collection to array
    for(var i = 0, childNodes = this.childNodes || []; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        children[i] = childNodes[i];
    }
    // Move children outside element
    for(i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = children[i];
        if(('tagName' in child) && child.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
        } else {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(child, this);
        }
    }
    // Remove now-empty anchor
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

To use (with jQuery):

```
$('a').each(unwrapAnchors);
```

To use (without jQuery):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
while(a.length) {
    unwrapAnchors.call(a[a.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: `var elem = arguments[0] || this`

Comment: @SLaks, used with jQuery, `el` would be the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

A <a> tag is not supposed to hold any other <a> tag, so a simple ungreedy regexp would do the trick (i.e. `string.match(/<a>(.*?)<\/a>/)`, but this example suppose the tags have no attribute).

Comment: That won't match any real tag.  Also, unclosed `<a>` tags are valid HTML.  (as opposed to XHTML)

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer. As for the unclosed `<a>` tags, I didn't know it was valid in HTML. That doesn't really make sense though, and I haven't seen such thing. So the regexp method will work most of the time if you trust the source of the string.

Comment: `<a>` tags are also anchors (for `#` links).  Anchors have no content.

Comment: Why on earth would you trust a string?

Comment: @SLaks, you might trust a string when you have control over its construction.

Comment: @Pikrass, your expression will fail if the `<a>` tag has any attributes (or trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a native (non-library) solution if performance is a concern.

```
function stripTag(str, tag) {
    var a, parent, div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    a = div.getElementsByTagName( tag );
    while( a[0] ) {
        parent = a[0].parentNode;
        while (a[0].firstChild) {
            parent.insertBefore(a[0].firstChild, a[0]);
        }
        parent.removeChild(a[0]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
alert( stripTag( my_string, 'a' ) );
```