# Write jQuery statement in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Wikipedia API to fetch just the first para of an article for which a keyword has been provided.

I have to extract formatted text from the JSON response but suppress some of the unwanted info like the sidebar (which is in a table & has the class name infobox) before I show it in a div whose id is wiki -

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?" +
            "action=mobileview&format=json&page=" +
            keyword + "&redirect=no&sections=0&prop=text&" +
            "sectionprop=toclevel%7Clevel%7Cline%7Cnumber" +
            "%7Cindex%7Cfromtitle%7Canchor&callback=?",
          function(json) { 
                    $('#wiki').html(json.mobileview.sections[0].text)
                              .find("dl,sup,.thumb,table.infobox,table.metadata")
                              .remove().end(); 
          }
);
```

I've [adapted the jQuery trick to remove tags/selectors](http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2012/02/03/jquery-remove-script-tags-from-a-string-of-html.html) from the JSON response containing the HTML code of the requested Wikipedia page. I want to use the above snippet in a Windows 8 Store app written in HTML/JS. I wish to convert the following line to native JavaScript and implement the selector removal code without using jQuery -

```
$('#wiki').html(json.mobileview.sections[0].text)
           .find("dl,sup,.thumb,table.infobox,table.metadata")
           .remove().end();
```

I'm a JavaScript newbie. Can anyone please convert this line to plain-vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var wiki = document.querySelector('#wiki');
wiki.innerHTML = json.mobileview.sections[0].text;

var content = wiki.querySelectorAll("dl,sup,.thumb,table.infobox,table.metadata");

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nodeName.toUpperCase() === "A")
        content[i].parentNode.insertBefore(content[i].firstChild, content[i]);

    content[i].parentNode.removeChild(content[i]);
}
```

This will work in most browsers including IE8 and higher.

Comment: thanks! that was very helpful. i also don't need to show hyperlinks within that content but retain the hyperlink text. I've looked at some samples here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536329/whats-the-best-way-to-strip-out-only-the-anchor-html-tags-in-javascript-given but could not adapt it for my requirement. How to remove anchor tags (but retain text) from the content by extending the same code?

Comment: @mvp: Assuming the anchors only have text and no nested elements, you can use the code in my updated answer. If the anchors are not part of the current DOM selection, add `,a` to the end of the selector, or `,a[href]` if you only want ones with an `href` attribute.